# Reactjs: can't access props from parent but are visible in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After following [this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/A23O4aUftXk) I have a SPA React app that authenticates a user with Passport against a third party (Strava) and returns JSON data that has an *accesstoken* that I'm trying to then use in another component for API requests.

When I use Chrome's Developer tools, I can see that the child component is receiving the props but I'm unable to access it when I try to initialize the state for the child component.

[Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLts3.png)

This is the parent component that gets all the JSON data and passes the accesstoken as a prop:

```js
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import UserProvider from "../contexts/UserProvider";
import CalculateSpeed from "../components/displays/CalculateSpeed";
import _ from "lodash";

const Profile = () => {

    const userData = useContext(UserProvider.context);
    return (
        <div className="page">
            <CalculateSpeed acccesToken={userData.token}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Profile;
```

And the child component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CalculateSpeed extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fastAF: false,
      accessToken: props.accessToken
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ fontSize: 20, color: "red", textAlign: "center", whiteSpace: "pre"}}>
        Accesstoken should be here {'\n'}
        { this.state.fastAF }
        But it isnt...
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CalculateSpeed
```

Everything I've seen when searching for an answer talked about `super(props)` in the constructor but that didn't solve my issue.

Comment: Can you please put a `console.log(props.accessTocken)` see whether you really get that props from your child component?

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
state = {
    fastAF: false,
    accessToken: this.props.accessToken
  }
```

instead of

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fastAF: false,
      accessToken: props.accessToken
    }
  }
```

Comment: Nope, still giving me the same issue